# Opencpu POST request times out in 90 seconds

Tags: r, opencpu

POST request to an OpenCPU function times out at 90 seconds.

```
response <- httr::POST(url, httr::config(timeout = 300, verbose = TRUE), httr::content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), body = list(myjson = jsoninput), encode = "form")
```

> Error: timeout reached (90.000000 sec)
>
> HTTP status code: 400

1. Per OpenCPU manual, we changed the following conf files and updated
   the default timelimit.post value to 300 seconds.

   /etc/opencpu/server.conf.d/server.conf

   /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/opencpu/config/defaults.conf
2. Despite these changes, we keep getting the same error. Although with
   a smaller data set, the request is processed successfully, but after
   almost 13MB of request object, it starts to time out.
3. In addition, rlimit.as setting is 4e9 (approx. 3.7 GB) and default timeout on apache conf file is 300 seconds.
4. Interestingly enough, the same request works when the function is
   invoked via opencpu/apache's test page. 
    https://servername/ocpu/test

Two questions:

1) How to confirm that the timeout (timelimit.post) overrides are honored by the opencpu/apache server?

2) Any other setting that we can try to change for a longer data processing call on OpenCPU?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting a cache after you raised `timelimit.post`?

Comment: I restarted the apache2 service and restarted the machine, but we're still facing the same issue. Any other cache folder i need to delete or change any cache related setting?

Comment: It sounds like you did everything OK. To confirm `timelimit.post` try posting something simple like `curl http://cloud.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R/Sys.sleep -d time=1000`

Comment: Thanks. I tested using the curl command too and the result is the same. 


timeout reached (90.000000 sec


In call:

tryCatch({
    if (length(priority))
        set_priority(priority)
    if (length(rlimits))
        set_rlimits(rlimits)
    if (length(gid))
        setgid(gid)
    if (length(uid))
        setuid(uid)
    if (length(profile))
        aa_change_profile(profile)
    if (length(device))
        options(device = device)
    graphics.off()
    options(menu.graphics = FALSE)
    serialize(withVisible(eval(orig_expr, parent.frame())), NULL)
}.........

Comment: Can you try updating the `timelimit.post` in `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` ?

Comment: That is the first file we changed and because it didn't work, we copied the file in the server.conf.d folder to essentially override it. 


etc/opencpu/server.conf.d/server.conf.

Based on the error, is it possible that R operation is getting timed out and not on apache/opencpu? Any existing restrictions in the REST API set up assuming web services are not mean for long/batch processing tasks?

Comment: I tried again updating the /etc/opencpu/server.conf file and after restarting the machine/opecpu, i got the same error. timeout reached (90.000000 sec)